# clip .o5m dataset with commandline tools instead within the GIS software

Tags: openstreetmap, command-line, osmfilter

I work with statewide OSM datasets (retrieved form geofabrik.de) I need just one county at the time tough. Especially for the buildings it takes quite some time before they all have loaded in QGIS.

Is there a way to clip the statewide dataset to a country wide with commandline applications (like osmfilter) so I don't have to do this within my GIS programm?